# No matter how many times i read this it doesn't click into my brain. Please explain it

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

Find a scenario in which data integrity cannot be ensured by your current primary keys and foreign keys.

I just dont get it. But just a guess would a scenario be whether an employee is assigned to a booking made by a client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data integrity is more than relational integrity...

1. You could have a column which value must remain between 1 and 100. Read about CHECK constraints
2. You could need a column which must contain a value. Read about NOT NULL and DEFAULT constraints
3. You could need some values (or combinations of values) to be unique. Read about unique indexes
4. In high performance scenarios it is possible to trick out the server. Read about isolation level, phantom reads...
5. If your application allows disconnected data manipulation you could get broken integrity while syncing. Read about replication

I'm sure there is still more to add...

Comment: I just dont get the part were it says " cannot be ensured by your current PK and FK "

Comment: @Joshbragen, well, all points I stated would break your data integrity and cannot be ensured by PKs and FKs... What is your problem?

Comment: @Joshbragen, if this solves your problem, it would be very kind of you to mark this as the accepted answer. If not, just call back...

Comment: Sorry, Just hard to get my head over it but i think i got it. So if say if i were to check a value lets say employeNo which is a FK in Booking. using. 

SELECT * FROM Booking
WHERE employeeNo IS NULL, If i get a value it means my data integrity check has failed as this attribute should have a value in it in every row. And to fix this add a IS NOT NULL to the attribute

Comment: @Joshbragen, This was an example where you should force the column 'employeeNo' never to be NULL. Without the `NOT NULL` constraint you could have bookings without an employee. The FK will ensure, that values must be set, which exist in the related table and that a row in the related table may not be changed or deleted if there are child rows somewhere else. Everything clear now?